# Get components linked to keywords in SDL Web 8

Tags: web8.5, keyword, component

I would like to know, how can we access the components linked to a particular Keyword in SDL Web 8, from our DXA Java web application.

Currently I do not see any field in my WebApp that maps to the component list for any keyword.

I see this link has it detailed for an Array of keywords. Is there anyway to do it for individual keywords.

As getTaxonomyContent takes the following parameters:

- an array of Keywords
- a Boolean to include branches (true) of the passed Keywords to
  retrieve content for, otherwise false for only content relating
  directly to the Keyword
- (optional) an additional Criteria (
  Com.Tridion.Broker.Querying.Criteria.Criteria)

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-AE9E11C7-9B02-4F55-99E2-8E6C69DA8B0F

Any help/suggestion would be really appreciated.
TIA.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems like you have already answered your own question?  You have found the API to get classified Components for a given (set of) Keyword(s).  Ok, it takes an array of Keywords, but you can create an array containing one item, right?

Comment: Yes, I can, however, the below line keeps requiring the 'criteria' even though its optional:  

                                                                                                    
String[] foundComponentURIS = relationManager.GetTaxonomyContent(selectedKeywords, false, criteria);

Comment: Is it worth adding your code and the _exact_ error to the example? Maybe there's an issue with the variable ```criteria``` itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that documentation link, **componentItemType** variable should be corrected to **criteria**

GetTaxonomyContent has following API methods:

```
    public string[] GetTaxonomyContent(Keyword taxonomyKeyword, bool includeBranches);
    public string[] GetTaxonomyContent(Keyword[] taxonomyKeywords, bool includeBranches);
    public string[] GetTaxonomyContent(Keyword taxonomyKeyword, bool includeBranches, Criteria additionalCriteria);
    public string[] GetTaxonomyContent(Keyword[] taxonomyKeywords, bool includeBranches, Criteria additionalCriteria);
```

Example with criteria:

```
int iComponentItemType = 16;
String selectedKeywordURI = "tcm:12-800-1024";
Keyword selectedKeywords;
TaxonomyFactory taxonomyFactory = new TaxonomyFactory();
selectedKeywords = taxonomyFactory.GetTaxonomyKeyword(selectedKeywordURI);
TaxonomyRelationManager relationManager = new TaxonomyRelationManager();
ItemTypeCriteria criteria = new ItemTypeCriteria(iComponentItemType);
String[] foundComponentURIS = relationManager.GetTaxonomyContent(selectedKeywords, true, criteria);
```

Example without criteria (optional):

```
String selectedKeywordURI = "tcm:12-800-1024";
Keyword selectedKeywords;
TaxonomyFactory taxonomyFactory = new TaxonomyFactory();
selectedKeywords = taxonomyFactory.GetTaxonomyKeyword(selectedKeywordURI);
TaxonomyRelationManager relationManager = new TaxonomyRelationManager();
String[] foundItemsURIS = relationManager.GetTaxonomyContent(selectedKeywords, true);
```

I hope it helps.